# Unordered list tree is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list, tree

I've got a tree where I use an Unordered list, the tree needs to be created based on the attributes found on the HTML frame, the only problem I'm having while collapsing/expanding the tree is that when I click on a child it collapses the whole thing, how can I prevent the whole node from collapsing.

Any help will be appreciated!

**Here's my code**

To spot out the problem, click on **firstItem2** then click **SecondItem4** to expand it, you'll notice that the whole thing collapses.

```js
$(".branch").each(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('dad') !== "") {
    $(this).stop().hide(500);
  }
});
$('.branch').on('mousedown', function() {
  dad = $(this).attr('id');
  toggleChildren(dad);
});

function toggleChildren(dad) {
  $('.branch').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('dad') == dad) {
      if ($(this).is(':visible') === false) {
        $(this).stop().show(500);
      } else {
        $(this).stop().hide(500);
      }
      //console.log("DAD: "+dad+"\nID: "+$(this).attr('id')+'\nDATA: '+$(this).text());
    }
  });
}
$('#node3').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="node1" dad="" class="branch">firstItem1
    <ul>
      <li id="node2" dad="node1" class="branch">SecondItem1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="node3" dad="" class="branch">firstItem2
    <ul>
      <li id="node4" dad="node3" class="branch">SecondItem2</li>
      <li id="node5" dad="node3" class="branch">SecondItem3</li>
      <li id="node6" dad="node3" class="branch">SecondItem4
        <ul>
          <li id="node7" dad="node6" class="branch">ThirdItem1</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tweaking some stuff up, I wasn't able to disable the by-clicking-on-me-you-are-clicking-on-my-parent feature, so I decided to change the HTML but not the attributes.

**Here's what was able to create:**

```js
 $('.branch').on('mousedown', function() {
   dad = $(this).attr('id');
   toggleChildren(dad);
 });

 function toggleChildren(dad) {
   $('.branch').each(function() {
     if ($(this).attr('dad') == dad) {
       if ($(this).is(':visible') === false) {
         $(this).stop().show(500);
       } else {
         $(this).stop().hide(500);
       }
       iterateChildren(this);
     }
   });
 }

 function iterateChildren(item) {
   dad = $(item).attr('id');
   $('.branch').each(function() {
     if ($(this).attr('dad') == dad) {
       if ($(this).is(':visible') !== false) {
         $(this).stop().hide(500);
       }
       iterateChildren(this);
     }
   });
 }
 $('.branch').each(function() {
   dad = $(this).attr('dad');
   marginLeft = $('#' + dad).css('margin-left');
   $(this).css({
     'margin-left': parseInt(marginLeft, 10) * 2
   });
 });
 $(".branch").each(function() {
   if ($(this).attr('dad') !== "") {
     $(this).stop().hide(500);
   }
 });
```

```css
  .branch {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<ul id="menu">
  <div id="node1" dad="" class="branch">firstItem1</div>
  <div id="node2" dad="node1" class="branch">SecondItem1</div>
  <div id="node3" dad="" class="branch">firstItem2</div>
  <div id="node4" dad="node3" class="branch">SecondItem2</div>
  <div id="node5" dad="node3" class="branch">SecondItem3</div>
  <div id="node6" dad="node3" class="branch">SecondItem4</div>
  <div id="node7" dad="node6" class="branch">ThirdItem1</div>
</ul>
```